# How to find the txPower in Bluetooth on IONIC

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth

I managed to display the scanned devices in my app using **[cordova-plugin-ble-central](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central)** and I can see the RSSI of each device, but I can't find the txPower. This parameter has two definitions:

1. The transmitted power of the peripheral.
2. The received power 1 meter away from the peripheral. (RSSI at 1 meter)

Any Ideas how to calculate it?

I have also used the package **[cordova-plugin-bluetoothle](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle)** but can't see the txPower.

Thanks,